# Adding list forms in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: list, visual-studio

In SharePoint Desinger it is possible to add a new forms to a list (example CustomeEditForm.aspx). Is there some method of doing this in Visual Studio 2010 and how is that done? And is ther some blog or site that describes this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todd Carter had a session on this on Ignite developer training.

These sessions are now public:
[SharePoint development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ff420377.aspx)